# Facebook JavaScript SDK - saving access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to work with Facebook JavaScript SDK. I had my code but it doesn't work well and I found [this](http://demos.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-javascript-sdk/). The problem on my site is that if I log-in and reload the page then I lost my data, I mean the access token is not saved, like there was no connection. As you can see on link I added, you can log-in, refresh the page and after few seconds (not immediately) everything is loaded. What should I add to my code? I paste it here but for now it is the same from site - I just need to understand why my token is not saved (why I lost it after reload).  In console, after log-in and refresh, trying to logout I've got `FB.logout() called without an access token.`

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  
      version    : 'v2.8' 
    });
    
    // Check whether the user already logged in
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
   getFbUserData();
  }
 });
};


(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function fbLogin() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            getFbUserData();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}

function getFbUserData(){
    FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'email'},
    function (response) {
        document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick","fbLogout()");
document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = 'Logout from Facebook';
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.email + '!';
    
    });
}


function fbLogout() {
    FB.logout(function() {
        document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick","fbLogin()");
document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You have successfully logout from Facebook.';
    });
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>

<!-- Facebook login or logout button -->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fbLogin()" id="fbLink"></a>

<!-- Display user profile data -->
<div id="userData"></div>
```

Comment: your code is missing something (window.fbAsyncInit), take a look at this example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: My bad while copying it. I will edit it. I have it in my code but It doesn't help. TY.